# What is the use of chanting the sahasranamam everyday?

Tags: stotra, vishnu-sahasranama

Everyday morning I hear the Vishnu Sahasranamam Stotram and I feel that my day is the happiest even though I face a little trouble. However I cannot leave or miss a day hearing the stotram.

Hence I need to explain to someone what is the use for doing the same everyday. And I need the explanation for myself for chanting everyday.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for Sri Sahasranama?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely

Comment: Asking for user's stories and experiences gives to opinion based answers. Do you mean Vishnu Sahasranamam or Sri Sahasranamam?  Please clarify.

Comment: If by Sri you mean Devi Lakshmi, then please remove vishnu-sahasranama tag from question.

Comment: Apologies for `Sri` instead of `Vishnu` however in my tags I have correctly updated as `vishnu-sahasranama`

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 6):

Read Vishnu SahasraNaama here - [**Vishnu SahasraNaama**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/vsahasranew.html?lang=sa)

In Mahabharata , Anushasana Parva, Vishnu SahasraNaama,
DevaVrata tells why one should read the SahasraNaama.

> इदं शृणुयान्नित्यं यश्चापि परिकीर्तयेत् ।
>   नाशुभं प्राप्नुयात्किञ्चित्सोऽमुत्रेह च मानवः ॥ २॥
>   Bhishma said-
>   Whoever listens or reads this Vishnu SahasraNaama never meets inauspiciousness in this or next life.
>
> वेदान्तगो ब्राह्मणः स्यात्क्षत्रियो विजयी भवेत् ।
>   वैश्यो धनसमृद्धः स्याच्छूद्रः सुखमवाप्नुयात् ॥ ३॥
>   Brahmin becomes endowed with knowledge of Veda completely, Kshattriya win the battles, Vaishya becomes wealthy and Shudra becomes happy.
>
> धर्मार्थी प्राप्नुयाद्धर्ममर्थार्थी चार्थमाप्नुयात् ।
>   कामानवाप्नुयात्कामी प्रजार्थी प्राप्नुयात्प्रजाम् ॥ ४॥
>   A righteousl person gets Righteousness, person desiring money gets money, person wanting a desire fulfills desire, and one wanting dominion gets a kingdom.
>
> भक्तिमान् यः सदोत्थाय शुचिस्तद्गतमानसः ।
>   सहस्रं वासुदेवस्य नाम्नामेतत्प्रकीर्तयेत् ॥ ५॥
>   The  Bhakta (devotee) who always waking up early getting clean and directing the mind in Vaasudeva , chants this SahasraNaama,
>
> यशः प्राप्नोति विपुलं ज्ञातिप्राधान्यमेव च ।
>   अचलां श्रियमाप्नोति श्रेयः प्राप्नोत्यनुत्तमम् ॥ ६॥
>   gets long fame of knowing great things, gets stable money, and gets unseconded Punya.
>
> न भयं क्वचिदाप्नोति वीर्यं तेजश्च विन्दति ।
>   भवत्यरोगो द्युतिमान्बलरूपगुणान्वितः ॥ ७॥
>   He never gets fears, and his valour and resplendence increases. He is freed of diseases and has a resplendence of lightning with strong body and qualities.
>
> रोगार्तो मुच्यते रोगाद्बद्धो मुच्येत बन्धनात् ।
>   भयान्मुच्येत भीतस्तु मुच्येतापन्न आपदः ॥ ८॥
>   Who is diseased is freed of diseases, who is in bondage is freed, a feared person is freed of fear, and an afflicted person is freed of problems.
>
> दुर्गाण्यतितरत्याशु पुरुषः पुरुषोत्तमम् ।
>   स्तुवन्नामसहस्रेण नित्यं भक्तिसमन्वितः ॥ ९॥
>   The person who always reads this SahasraNaama with full devotion for Purushottama Vishnu , is easily freed from obstacles.
>
> वासुदेवाश्रयो मर्त्यो वासुदेवपरायणः ।
>   सर्वपापविशुद्धात्मा याति ब्रह्म सनातनम् ॥ १०॥
>   Who is in refuge of Vaasudeva, and is utmostly devoted to Him, that mortal being is freed of all sins and attains the Supreme Brahman.